# How to access HTML pages in Hexo?

Tags: html, hexo

I'm trying to link my **hexo page i.e. post-5.md** to **a another webpage (game.html)** that I dropped in `/source/_posts/post-5`.

I can access an image **i.e. image.gif** that I dropped into the assets folder but not another webpage.

help?

*I have changed the following setting in `my _config.yml` file.

```
  post_asset_folder: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can genrate the html firstly(using hexo g), then the target page's URL should be [domain name]+[target page's path under the public folder].